# PHP run Python script but result do not appear at frontend web

Tags: php, python

First, I search all topics that relate to my topic but I do not get output as them.
I run Python script via PHP's exec functions (exec, shell_exec, passthru, system) but the result do not show on browser(white screen). So, I test in CLI, It works!!! I get result.

[result from CLI](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mW7xLabiiSaq4LpnmziF29ispe1CSQGg/view?usp=sharing)

readpython.php :

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$command = escapeshellcmd("sudo python /var/www/html/access01/scripts/readRFID.py");
$output = shell_exec($command);
echo $output;

?>
```

readrfid.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import SimpleMFRC522

reader = SimpleMFRC522.SimpleMFRC522()

try:
        id, text = reader.read()
        print(id)
        #print(text)
finally:
        GPIO.cleanup()
```

Is there another ways to show result on browser ?
or maybe I missing some libraries or extensions in my server?
I use apache2, mariaDB, PHP7.0 and Python2.7.12

Best regards.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a space between `python` and `/path/to/.py`

Comment: Sorry my bad. I did not check my post. In the code already has space between python and /path/to/.py

Comment: @striderblue does using `sudo` expect password input? did you try taking out `sudo`?